# Software data visualization

Tags: open-source, odbc, real-time, data-visualization

I have NO IDEA whether this question belongs here... I'll ask it anyway, perhaps someone knows the answer or can direct me to a more suitable forum to ask a question like this.

Here we go...

I am looking for a (preferable open source) software program that allows me to easily visualize data. I have a database that collects summary data from many other project databases (every time a data is added to a project database and is closed an update is sent to the summary database, including a timestamp). Id like to have the option to plot project progres, or money spent, or any other thing I can think of in an interactive environment. When I close my eyes, I see an application with drop down menus to select a specific project and 'buttons' or tabs that visually show project proces (e.g. money spent or number of forms processed vs. number of expected forms processes in the past 6 months).

Id like the option to make a ODBC connection to the summary database, so that I always get a fresh version of the data (real time) when I want to get an overview of how the projects are running.

Im convinced something like this exists, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: Do you prefer a desktop or browser-based app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new project in the yard, which might be the perfect fit for your needs:

[Data Visualization Software Lab](http://datavisualizationsoftwarelab.com)

That library is purely HTML5 based and very interactive - try the demo.

Here is how you put it in your project:

```
chart = new TimeChart({
     container: document.getElementById("timeChartContainer"),
     data: {
         dataFunction: function(from, to, step, success, fail) {
             success({
                 "unit":"M",
                 "values":[...],
                 "dataLimitFrom":1338558028000,
                 "dataLimitTo":1372567075000
             });
         },
         units: ["M"],
         area: {
             initialDisplayPeriod: "max"   
         }
     },
     width: 750,
     height: 300
});
```

See [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UudRP/1/)  for full example.

Library is in beta at the moment. Dual licensing to be provided.

Snapshot:

[image: TimeChart example]